# Dangers of currents for windsurfers

Tags: safety, sea, water-sports, windsurfing

Can sea currents be dangerous for surfers? How common would this be? Should I ask locals about currents before surfing at a new spot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My surfing/windsurfing knowledge is limited. But **yes** they can be dangerous and **yes** you should seek knowledge on currents before surfing anywhere.

There are currents that can force you against rocks, or [into sea caves](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-dorset-26646104) or under water of the dreaded rip tides.

[Rip tides](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rip_current) are nasty and can suck you out to sea. My mate was caught in one of these once and in a matter of seconds he was in seriously deep water.

Here's an animation of how rip tides work:

[image]

The tide builds up pressure behind a sand bank, eventually this bank breaks and the build up of water empties into deeper water, taking everything and everyone with it. To exit a rip tide you swim side ways to the beach, **not against it**. You won't win against the current.